# Will apple reject the app if we navigate a page on click of UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, navigation, uitouch

I have used 4 images and use touches began method to detect user's touch on particular image. I navigate to 4 different views based on location of touch. Will apple approve his kind of design.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGRect rectLocation1 = CGRectMake(20, 399, 72, 61);
    CGRect rectLocation2 = CGRectMake(91, 399, 72, 61);

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rectLocation1, touchLocation)) {
    //navigation
    }

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rectLocation2, touchLocation)) {
    //Navigation
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problems with that. But why can't you use 4 buttons instead, using the image as background on the buttons. That will be much smoother.
 Or are your images not rectangular?

Comment: i cant use button in this case as i have been given 1 default image & 4 selected state images. A single image has impression for 4 buttons. Each selected state image will have a single zoomed out button n other 3 buttons to be normal as in normal state image. I will assign these 4 selected state images to image view based on where the user clicks in the normal state image thus giving the user a illusion that they are clicking on the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not, there's nothing wrong with this. What particular part makes you think it might be rejected? Perhaps we can help explain why it's not a problem.

The [full set of guidelines is posted here](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?appIdKey=d4f7d769c2abecc664d0dadfed6a67f943442b5e9c87524d4587a95773750cea&path=//appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html). (Apple Developer login is required)

Comment: i thought that UIimageView was meant only for displaying images and not for navigation of pages.

Comment: You've used it a little unconventionally, but not in anyway that would cause your app to be rejected. You've basically just written a stripped down version of UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it won't be rejected. You don't use any private API whatsoever.

Have a look at the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html)

Comment: I agree, but keep in mind that not using private APIs does not always mean that the app will not be rejected